# Extension of prime ideals to polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> For a commutative ring $R$ prove that the ideal $P[X]$ is prime if $P$ is prime ideal in $R$.

I know that

$$R[X]/P[X]≅(R/P)[X].$$

Also an ideal $I$ of a commutative ring $R$ is prime if and only if $R/I$ is an integral domain.

How to proceed further?

Comment: If $P$ is prime, $R/P$ is a domain, so $(R/P)[X]$ is again a domain. (Think about the degree of a product of nonzero polynomials with coefficients in a domain.)

Comment: Can you just tell me the steps to solve it.

Comment: Ben's hint should be more than sufficient.  If $(R/P)[X]$ is an integral domain, then you should be able to conclude your proof using only the statements you've mentioned in your post.